# Is there a way to get a "docstring" of a function?

Tags: documentation, ocaml

To get a footprint of a function/module,
I can do:

```
module type S = module type of Stack;;
```

What should I do to get a description/docstring of some function?

Comment: The `#show` command in utop is useful, too.  As answers indicate, documentation isn't available in utop by default.  In a language like Clojure, the docstring is in effect stored with the function.  This would be unnatural for OCaml, since functions are compiled down to very low-level code.  In addition to RichouHunter's answer, a package that should allow docstring-like functionality in utop is ocp-index-top:  [https://github.com/reynir/ocp-index-top](https://github.com/reynir/ocp-index-top).  I haven't tried it.  You can also build your own documentation pages with `odoc` or `ocamldoc`.

Comment: I often use ocamlbrowser (which is now provided separately), and have a peek to the mli files from it, whenever I need to refresh my memory about some function in the standard libs (the mli files there are rather well commented).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ocp-browser`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ocp-browser/), which provides a command-line interface to browse all packages you have installed.

It has a search feature, and by pressing the space bar, you can see the documentation associated to a function.

Here's a example with the `Stack` module.

[image: ocp-browser]

**Update: June 22, 2017**

A few days ago, a package named [`ocp-index-top`](https://github.com/reynir/ocp-index-top) was published on OPAM, allowing you to see the documentation inside of an OCaml toplevel.

[image]

Comment: Cool to see my package getting suggested! Perhaps I should fix some of its bugs then :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do so. Actually, the signature should give you a good insight of what the function is supposed to do and if you're not sure you'll have to read the description in the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/).

As a side note, there's an easier way to look at the signature of anything (function, module, exception ...) which is

```
# #show ident;;
```

As written [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#sec276),

> At start-up, the toplevel system contains implementations for all the modules in the the standard library.

I understand it as `only the .cm* files are loaded` and in these files you won't find the comments that document the functions. I'm, then, almost sure that you can't read the documentation of a function from the toplevel.

But, really, I think you get used to understanding the purpose of a function from its name and signature

Comment: Yes, I know this, but it is only a signature. Sometimes you really need the documentaion (but anyway thank you for the help and +1)